# Get one day and monthly sum of amount from one table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sum

I want to write the query to calculate the amount as per current day and monthly.

I have **TransactionID, Date, Amount** columns in my **Charge** table.

I want it in this format:

```
currentDayAmount              TotalMonthlyAmount
$12305                        $236589                  --suppose on 31 Aug 2011
$62598                        $365489                  --suppose on 30 Sep 2011
```

Here CurrentDayAmount is which date I entered to excute the query and TotalMonthlyAmount is which month I entered the date. It means I want to execute with three dates. First is for the day which I want to run the query and last two is range of dates which is needs to total monthly amount.
I execute the below query but shows the correct data but shows in rows.

```
select sum(c.amount) 
from charge c 
where c.eDate between '09/16/2011' and '09/17/2011'
union all 
select sum(c1.amount) 
from charge c1
where c1.eDate between '09/01/2011' and '09/20/2011'
```

Result

```
$33256.25
$705826.36
```

I want this data in columns as

```
current            Monthly
$33256.25          $705826.36
```

I hope this information is enough to understand u what I want to do.
Please give any suggestion or query to resolve my issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    currentDayAmount = (
                         SELECT
                            SUM(c.amount)
                         FROM
                            charge c
                         WHERE
                            c.eDate BETWEEN '09/16/2011' AND '09/17/2011'
                       )
  , TotalMonthlyAmount = (
                           SELECT
                            SUM(c1.amount)
                           FROM
                            charge c1
                           WHERE
                            c1.eDate BETWEEN '09/01/2011' AND '09/20/2011'
                         )
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN c.edate BETWEEN '09/16/2011' AND '09/17/2011' THEN c.amount 
             ELSE 0 
           END), 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN c.edate BETWEEN '09/01/2011' AND '09/20/2011' THEN c.amount 
             ELSE 0 
           END), 
FROM   charge c
```

Comment: more elegant, but I get fewer logical reads with mine using a non clustered index `ON edate INCLUDE ( amount )` (i tested using adventureworks sample database)